# How to create a folder or file using a specific user permission in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: permissions, 14.04

For the instance, let's say `omar` is running and logged in to the system and `demo` is just another user in the system . Now `omar` wants to create a file or folder under `/var/www/` using `demo` user's permission. `omar` doesn't want to create a file with as usual procedure and give permission to `demo` user using `chmod` or `chown`. How this can be achieved?

Comment: If `demo` has root privileges then `omar` can make new folder (as a `demo` user) by `sudo -u demo mkdir /var/www/newfolder`. (to create/delete under filesystem, user must have root privileges)

Answer (score 1):

The user omar would have to either have root access or know the password of demo.

He can su to demo's access and create files under demo's permission with:

```
$ su demo
```

He would be prompt for the password of "demo" and could proceed to create the files with the desired permission.

He could do the same with root permission with:

```
$ sudo su demo
```

Or he could directly change the permission with:

```
$ sudo chown demo /var/www/[folder to change]
```

Since the folder you want to create is in the /var/www area, by default neither omar or demo would have write access to that particular folder and would need root access to start the action.